# Expo v49.0.0 + react-native-chart-kit + android : "View config getter callback for component 'RNSVGGroup' must be a function (received `undefined`)"

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-chart-kit

When using react-native-chart-kit sample with Android as device on expo version v48.0.0, all goes fine.
But when i change expo version to v49.0.0, I get the following message error:
View config getter callback for component 'RNSVGGroup' must be a function (received `undefined`)

Do you know how to fix that bug?
Thanks

Sample code is available here: https://snack.expo.dev/PgspKOQO9qnzXPNDF5cIZ?platform=android

I downloaded the project from expo, but did not find any RNSVGGroup reference.